# Windows 10 / Windows Server 2016 software compatibility

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-10

I just installed a software on my Windows 10 computer that works fine.
Its an old software so it needs visual c++ redistribuables 2010 that I installed (both x86 and x64, latest SP1 versions) 
I tried to install it on a Windows server 2016 with the same redistribuables but I get an

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)

error.

It would be hard to find the solution like this... I only want to know if there are some major incompatibilities between windows 10 and server 2016 or if my software should be able to start normally on this machine

Comment: More details on the name of what you are trying to install, any relevent events in the event log, and troubleshooting steps you've taken would help others help you.

Comment: Thanks Jim but I don't want people to solve my install, just to tell me if I missed any big incompatibility as I'm not aware of those softwares compatibilities. Furthermore, the program I'm trying to install has (sadly) no logging and all I tried was installing the C++ redistribuables as mentioned in the post

Comment: Windows Server 2016 uses the same code base as Windows 10 version 1607.  Anything that depends on features introduced in later versions of Windows 10 won't work.  That seems unlikely to be the problem in this case, more likely the software needs .NET 3 installed or some other prerequisite that you're not aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Windows Server 2016 uses the same code base as Windows 10 version 1607.
>   Harry Johnston comment